# React: question about using ref and useLayoutEffect to determine if a component is mounted or unmounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component like this

```js
function App() {
  const mounted = useRef()
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    mounted.current = true
    return () => {
      console.log('unmounted') // this does not get called when I unmount the component
      mounted.current = false
    }
  }, [])

  if (mounted.current) {
    console.log('mounted')
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {/* this hello world div doesn't get rendered on the screen, I thought useLayoutEffect would be called before browser paints screen */}
      {mounted.current && <div>hello world</div>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I know that `useEffect` serves the purpose too. I used `useLayoutEffect` is because it runs a bit earlier than `useEffect`. According to this https://github.com/donavon/hook-flow hook flow diagram.

My question is:

1. After I unmount the component, I don't see `console.log('unmounted')` gets run
2. I was expecting `<div>hello world</div>` to get rendered on the screen after I refresh the page since I the `useLayoutEffect` callback would run before browser paints the screen by that time when it paints the screen, the ref is set to true by the callback.

Answer (score 1):

> I was expecting hello world to get rendered on the screen after I refresh the page since I the useLayoutEffect callback would run before browser paints the screen by that time when it paints the screen, the ref is set to true by the callback.

Although `useLayoutEffect` runs more quickly than `useEffect`, *it's still asynchronous*. It's similar to the difference between `setTimeout(fn, 0)` and `setTimeout(fn, 60)`. The `useLayoutEffect` callback will not run until after the functional component has returned, but it *will* run before the user can see the new element.

So, since `mounted.current` is false the first time the component renders, and since no state changes occur, it doesn't re-render, and `hello world` doesn't appear.

> After I unmount the component, I don't see console.log('unmounted') gets run

Works fine here, I see it:

```js
function App() {
  const mounted = React.useRef()
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    mounted.current = true
    return () => {
      console.log('unmounted') // this does not get called when I unmount the component
      mounted.current = false
    }
  }, [])

  if (mounted.current) {
    console.log('mounted')
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {/* this hello world div doesn't get rendered on the screen, I thought useLayoutEffect would be called before browser paints screen */}
      {mounted.current && <div>hello world</div>}
    </div>
  )
}
const Outer = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(true);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShow(false);
    }, 2000);
  }, []);
  return (
    show ? <App /> : null
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<Outer />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```